# Customize Acumatica bulit-in dropdown list with conditions

Tags: acumatica, dropdown

I have used the answer to Woody's question at 
[Is there a easy way to customize Acumatica build-in dropdown list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34096583/is-there-a-easy-way-to-customize-acumatica-build-in-dropdown-list) to customize several dropdown lists. Thank you for the guidance with that one. I want to further customize a different drop-down list based on the Class ID and the Status of an Acumatica Case. I am not sure at all how to achieve this. Can anyone provide advice please?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Please specify the problem you encountered.

Comment: Sorry. For example, if the Class ID is "Technical Support", and Status is "Open" I want to offer a set of Reasons that applies to that scenario. If the Class ID is other than Technical Support, and the Status is Open, then the standard dropdown of Reasons applies. I do not know how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to write proper 'Search' BQL to get the result, you can use the PXSelector attribute. If you use 'Current' it will use the the current documents field value. So as per your case, you can use the current ClassID and Status to dynamically populate your selector.

Eg:

```
[PXSelector(typeof(Search<DiscountSequence.discountSequenceID,
            Where<DiscountSequence.discountID, Equal<Current<DiscountSequence.discountID>>>>))]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am having a look at this. Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0):

I propose you to consider customizable selector, with which you can completely control all your data which will be displayed. Here is [example](http://blog.zaletskyy.com/custom-selector-in-acumatica) of implementation.

Comment: Thank you very much for this response. I am also looking at this method, and think it just might be useful also for other more complicated customisations.

Comment: I have been unable to determine what the DRDocumentRecord.refNbr type is in the SelectCustomerContractAttribute function - I believe it needs to be replaced with CRCase in my application but am unsure. In reading the code, it is very clear what you are doing, and easy to understand that replacing items like ContractBillingSchedule in IEnumerable GetRecords with my requirements is what I have to do. Would you be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: DAC class with refNbr type and RefNbr field. For now I don't have access to that code, so can't say exactly.